# Rails 7.0 schema has arbitrary precision: 6 added on my timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a new rails app, when I am running the migrations the schema.rb is changing, a new param precision is added to my timestamps.

Where does this precision new param comes from?

```
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
```

Comment: No idea, but that is the default precision for timestamps, so it should not matter.

Answer (score 13):

`precision` is added by the [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#add_timestamps`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/aed8feae3b7a3f7df59de69355cc3bda1d5479d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L1322) method.

It's not arbitrary but pretty appropriate for timestamp attributes (microseconds precision vs seconds precision), if the RDBMS supports it.

Those defaults have been there for [at least 3 years](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/57015cdfa2083351f64a82f7566965172a41efcb) now (since Rails 6.0).

Since [the summer of 2021](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42297) `#add_column` and `#column` methods define them too. So if you upgrade to [Rails 7.0.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44571#issuecomment-1059295012) — `precision: 6` will be removed from `schema.rb` as it's now an internal logic.

You can find some relevant migration guidelines in the Active Record [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-702-february-08-2022).